# MassTransit new consumer (and di scope) for every message with prefetchcount > 1

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm trying to set things up with `MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration` and experimenting with PrefetchCount. I noticed that for multiple messages sometimes the same consumer is used.

Is there any way to force masstransit to create consumer for every message?

My service logic needs new di scope for every message and as far as I understand it's only possible if we would create consumer every time.

UPD

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/axle-h/MassTransit.RabbitMq.Extensions.Hosting) for registering consumers and publishers.

[Here you can see](https://github.com/axle-h/MassTransit.RabbitMq.Extensions.Hosting/blob/master/src/MassTransit.RabbitMq.Extensions.Hosting/Configuration/MassTransitRabbitMqHostingBuilder.cs#L91), that it registers consumers with `TryAddTrancient()`. Could this be a problem? I still think di container should produce consumers for every request.

Seems like this is not intentional behavior, I'll look into my problem deeper.

Comment: Please at least provide the code you're using to register consumers.

Comment: If you have registered your consumer as scoped, and are using the MS DI extensions for MassTransit, a new consumer should be resolved from the container for each message. Higher prefetch counts lead to higher degrees of concurrency, with multiple consumer instances running at the same time.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev 
I've updated the post. I use a wrapper library, but I linked a line of code where it registers consumers.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson
Yeah, sure, I understand this. I set breakpoints to constructor and to `Consume()` method of my consumer. And then saw single constructor call with multiple Consume calls. I definitely didn't register my consumer as singleton, so I'm quite confused with this behavior. I also linked a library I use for registering consumers.

Comment: That library is a wreck, and it isn't using the MS DI consumer scope provider, so scopes aren't being created at all: https://github.com/axle-h/MassTransit.RabbitMq.Extensions.Hosting/blob/master/src/MassTransit.RabbitMq.Extensions.Hosting/Configuration/MassTransitRabbitMqHostingConfigurator.cs#L53 -- that library needs some cleanup to make it reasonable.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson oh I see. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using `MassTransit.AspNetCore` package that uses

Please go through the [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/configuration.html#masstransit-and-aspnet-core), which includes samples.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services
        services.AddHealthChecks();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Register your consumers if the need dependencies
        services.AddScoped<SomeDependency>()
        services.AddScoped<OrderConsumer>();

        // Register MassTransit
        services.AddMassTransit(
            provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var host = cfg.Host("localhost", host => 
                { 
                    host.Username("guest");
                    host.Password("guest");
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "submit-order", ep =>
                {
                    ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
                    ep.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));

                    ep.Consumer<OrderConsumer>(provider);
                });
            }),
            x => x.AddConsumer<OrderConsumer>());
    }

    // everything else
}
```

Comment: Any chance this is still relevant for the newer versions?